# Error when Run the example test on the gomobile connection

Tags: ios, swift, go

I'm trying to run a Gomobile test on the terminal here is my code
I have done like instruction from https://www.sitepoint.com/ios-and-android-programming-with-go/

1. `go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile`
2. `gomobile init`
3. `gomobile build -target=ios golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic`

Which gives me the error:

> gomobile: go build -tags ios -ldflags=-w -o=/var/folders/4q/2vddqkyd3rv4tvzfbnsssbkm0000gn/T/gomobile-work-977299939/amd64 golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic failed: exit status 2
>           # golang.org/x/mobile/example/basic
>   /Users/ibct/.gvm/gos/go1.9.6/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed: exit status 1
>
> ld: building for iOS simulator, but linking in object file built for OSX, file '/var/folders/4q/2vddqkyd3rv4tvzfbnsssbkm0000gn/T/go-link-176961670/000003.o' for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you find a solution?